# Nvidia-drivers-418 causes fsck to hang on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, fsck, gpu-driver

I was using nouveau drivers before I found out that it's not up to par with nvidia's proprietary drivers

I decided to install the nvidia-driver-418 (proprietary) then after I rebooted, ubuntu launched fsck, it looked like everything is going [ OK ] but then it got stuck on the last line saying "fsck-cancel-message: Ctrl-C..."

At that point I waited for about 10 mins, nothing changed,
i looked at the HDD-LED indicator but it shows no activity.

I fixed it by restarting my PC and uninstalling nvidia-driver-418 via GRUB.

Everything seems fine now.

But I still want to use proprietary drivers, is there any workaround for this?

Picture of the screen
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2dz.jpg)

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001380sv00001569sd00001380bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ mokutil --sb-state
EFI variables are not supported on this system

$ test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"
Legacy(bios)

$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display                
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:29 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

$ dkms status
(nothing)

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
(nothing)

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Palit Microsystems Inc. GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [1569:1380]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` 2. `mokutil --sb-state` 3. `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"` 4. `sudo lshw -c video`  5. `dkms status` 6. `lsmod | grep nvidia` 7. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and 8 `lspci -knn | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)"`

Comment: here are the outputs:
https://pastebin.com/FV1mDaHC

Comment: You can use `e` on grub menu entry, go to line with `quiet splash` and change it to `quiet splash fastboot`. Then `fsck` isn't run at all. It's a work around like you asked for... Most people probably want `fsck` run at least once a month even though it takes a minute or so to run.

Comment: Even if I want to run fsck, it might get stuck again.

Here's the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2dz.jpg

It's stuck on that screen, I checked the HDD LED indicator to see there's any activity but the LED is not even turning on.

Comment: @gghavoc112, from the command output, you must install **Nvidia 430** ( NOT  **418**) which is the recommended one (refer command output: `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`). At present you are with nouveau drivers. Before attempting **430**  installation, please talk more about your computer system. Is it a laptop? Is it dual-booted?  It seems that your system is installed with bios(legacy). Why did you choose BIOS(legacy) over EFI? Please reply. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried **Nvidia 430**, same result. It's a Desktop PC. I'm dual-booting Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

Comment: Can you verify your windows 10 is installed in `efi `or `bios(legacy)`, please? Press the `Windows + R` keys, type `msinfo32.exe` in `Run` dialog box, and then press `Enter` to open `System Infomation `window. In the right pane of `System Summary,` you should see the `BIOS MODE` line. Check the value whether it is  `Legacy` or `UEFI`. Please report. Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 is using MBR, so legacy, I had to match my Ubuntu installation to Windows 10, so I also installed it using legacy.

Comment: Please check your Motherboard BIOS Firmware is up to date. If not, please upgrade.

Comment: it is up to date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93436/discussion-between-marmayogi-and-gghavoc112).